# Rails - Deploying to Heroku with duplicate routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes, clearance

I'm deploying my Rails app that uses the clearance gem to Heroku. Everything works fine in development but I'm running into trouble with the gem generated routes I get.

When attempting to deploy to Heroku, I get the error...

```
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'sign_in'


You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
remote:        http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

I'm not seeing where to restrict the duplicates or where they would be generated with any of my resources:

Please see routes.rb file below

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :passwords, controller: "clearance/passwords", only: [:create, :new]
  resource :session, controller: "clearance/sessions", only: [:create]

  resources :users, controller: "clearance/users", only: [:create] do
    resource :password,
      controller: "clearance/passwords",
      only: [:create, :edit, :update]
  end

  get "/sign_in" => "clearance/sessions#new", as: "sign_in"
  delete "/sign_out" => "clearance/sessions#destroy", as: "sign_out"
  get "/sign_up" => "clearance/users#new", as: "sign_up"

  get 'newSignUp', to: 'signups#new'
  post 'newSignUp', to: 'signups#create'

  get 'newTrip', to: 'trips#new'
  post 'newTrip', to: 'trips#create'

  get 'trips/:id/send_itinerary' => 'trips#send_itinerary', as: :trips_send_itinerary



  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  get 'static_pages/contact'


  resources :signups
  resources :tripitems
  resources :trips

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the gems [GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance), it looks like I raked the routes earlier and even though config.routes was set to false in the initializer, there was a conflict generate in the generated resources in production.

I wound up deleting the raked routes and making config.routes=true.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has to do with the `clearance` gem.

I am not totally familiar with the gem, so as per usual, I checked out the github and found the following:

```
# config/routes.rb
if Clearance.configuration.routes_enabled?
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :passwords,
      controller: 'clearance/passwords',
      only: [:create, :new]

    resource :session,
      controller: 'clearance/sessions',
      only: [:create]

    resources :users,
      controller: 'clearance/users',
      only: Clearance.configuration.user_actions do
        resource :password,
          controller: 'clearance/passwords',
          only: [:create, :edit, :update]
      end

    get '/sign_in' => 'clearance/sessions#new', as: 'sign_in'
    delete '/sign_out' => 'clearance/sessions#destroy', as: 'sign_out'

    if Clearance.configuration.allow_sign_up?
      get '/sign_up' => 'clearance/users#new', as: 'sign_up'
    end
  end
end
```

This is basically creating the same routes for you, only if the config `routes_enabled?` is true.

You need to configure `clearance` as follows to handle the routes yourself:

```
config.routes = false
```

Comment: the config.routes was already set to 'false' in the initializer.

Comment: @got2jam read your answer, very weird, but glad you got things to work properly.

Comment: Yea, I'm going to do a little bit more digging into this. Clearance recommends that you do turn the user off the generate routes so I can that makes sense. I'm learning rails for a quick and dirty MVP but kind of getting enamored by it so I'll be diving into routes more

Thanks for your help